# Linq To Entities Aggregate sum

Tags: linq-to-objects

I have the following query:

```
var query = (from o in orders
group new
{
    o.OrderDate,
    o.paymenttotal
}
by new
{
    o.OrderDate.Value.Month,
    o.OrderDate.Value.Year
} into grouping
orderby grouping.Key.Month
select new
{
    grouping,
    totalPayment = grouping.Sum (g => g.paymenttotal)
});

query.Dump();
```

The query works very well and it gives the break down of the total for each month, I want to extend the query to also add the sum of All totals, so I can have a "Footer Total".

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called `WITH ROLLUP` in SQL. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401623/1124792) has an implementation in LINQ.