# CONVERT SQL ROLLUP INTO LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM CustomerOrders
GROUP BY OrderID WITH ROLLUP
```

How can i convert the above sql into linq?

Comment: How about you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. It is useful as a query language for ORMs (I assume you use EF instead of eg NHibernate?). It's *NOT* a query language for analytical queries as this

Comment: You can execute raw SQL queries with Entity Framework and have it map the result to a class. This is the only way to execute this particular query. Of course, ORMs aren't meant for reporting/analytical queries anyway. A micro-ORM like Dapper would be preferable for such queries as you'll end up creating the query by hand anyway

Comment: This answer can probably help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401623/4444757