# Convert List<List<string>> to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq: List of lists to a long list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649773/linq-list-of-lists-to-a-long-list)

I have convert it using LINQ.
`List<List<string>>` to `List<string>.`
If the leaves overlap one. Must be In one line.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure if I understand what you need.

Comment: "If the leaves overlap one" what do you mean by that? Do you want to simply flatten the list, or do you only want distinct elements, or something entirely different?

Comment: SelectMany is what exactly I was looking for. Thank you all.

Comment: When I typed differently I found even otherwise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462879/convert-listlistt-into-listt-in-c I apologize for repeating questions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
input.SelectMany(l => l).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit under specified.

```
input.SelectMany(list=>list).ToList()
```

This puts all strings that are part of any list into the result list. If you need only unique elements add `.Distinct` between the `SelectMany` and the `ToList`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<string>> listOfLists = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> flattenedList = ListOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```